# Как в Hibernate создать запрос с параметром?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Всем привет. Изучаю Hibernate, делаю запрос

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
em = emf.createEntityManager();
System.out.println("Write min price");
int minPrice = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Write max price");
int maxPrice = scanner.nextInt();

Query query = em.createQuery(
    "select m from Menu m where m.price> :minPrice AND m.price<:maxPrice", Menu.class);
query.setParameter("maxPrice", maxPrice);
query.setParameter("minPrice", minPrice);
List<Menu> menus = query.getResultList();
for (Menu menu: menus){
    System.out.println(menu);
}
```

В этой строчке программа вылетает. Не могу правильно сделать запрос с параметром - query.setParameter("maxPrice", maxPrice);

Если же без параметра в самом запросе прописать данные то все норм.

```
Query query = em.createQuery(
    "select m from Menu m where m.price>5 AND m.price<15", Menu.class);
//query.setParameter("maxPrice", "maxPrice");
// query.setParameter("minPrice", "minPrice");
List<Menu> menus = query.getResultList();
for (Menu menu: menus){
    System.out.println(menu);
}
```

Я так понимаю, что не правильно устанавливаю параметр или прописываю в самом запросе его. В чем проблема?

Вот ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [15] did not match expected type [java.lang.Float (n/a)]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:874)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.access$000(QueryImpl.java:80)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl$ParameterRegistrationImpl.bindValue(QueryImpl.java:248)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:620)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:180)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:49)
at HibernateHomework1.App.selectDishesByPrice(App.java:77)
at HibernateHomework1.App.main(App.java:31)
```

Comment: "программа вылетает" с каким сообщением?

Comment: Я так понимаю, если вы используете EntityManager, значит вы пользуетесь JPA, советую вам начать работать с Spring Data JPA, там таких проблем не будет.

Comment: Добавил ошибку в описание

Comment: Поменять последовательность строк, так как они идут в Запросе. 
`"select m from Menu m where m.price> :minPrice AND m.price<:maxPrice", Menu.class);
    query.setParameter("minPrice", minPrice);
    query.setParameter("maxPrice", maxPrice);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. Может когда-то кому-то поможет или поможет найти ошибку. 
В коде было `int minPrice = scanner.nextInt();`
а в базе данных тип поля был float
Глупая ошибка

Answer (score -1):

Поменять последовательность строк, так как они идут в Запросе:

```
[... "select m from Menu m where m.price> :minPrice AND m.price<:maxPrice", 
Menu.class); query.setParameter("minPrice", minPrice); 
query.setParameter("maxPrice", maxPrice);
]
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: но все равно не помогло, та же ошибка